How was Schinzel's Hypothesis H checked by computer up to $10^9$?
Here is the statement of Schinzel's hypothesis (also known as Schinzel's Hypothesis H), an unproven conjecture, according to Wolfram MathWorld:

If $f_1(x)$, ..., $f_s(x)$ are irreducible polynomials with integer coefficients such that no integer $n>1$ divides $f_1(x)$, ..., $f_s(x)$ for all integers $x$, then there should exist infinitely many $x$ such that $f_1(x)$, ..., $f_s(x)$ are simultaneously prime.

It is stated on the page that Conroy verified this conjecture up to $n = 10^9$.
Conroy's result has a page "A sequence related to a conjecture of Schinzel" in the Journal of Integer Sequences. It states that Hypothesis H implies that every positive integer $n$ can be represented as $\frac{p+1}{q+1}$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime. Conroy verifies that this holds for every positive integer $n$ to up $10^9$.
However, this doesn't seem to be the same thing as checking Hypothesis H up to $n=10^9$. I also can't find a proof that the statement "every positive integer can be represented as $\frac{p+1}{q+1}$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime" implies Hypothesis H. The citation "Sur certaines hypothèses concernant les nombres premiers" from Conroy's article only seems to prove that Hypothesis H implies this representability principle, but I can't find a proof there that shows the converse implication. In addition, it seems strange to say that Hypothesis H is definitively checked for $n$ up to $10^9$, since it doesn't seem possible to write a computer program which verifies in over $10^9$ different cases that there are infinitely many $x$ with some property.
My question is: is there any source showing that the statement "every positive integer up to $10^9$ can be written as $\frac{p+1}{q+1}$ for $p$ and $q$ prime" implies that Hypothesis H holds up to $n = 10^9$? If not, is it fair to say that Hypothesis H has been verified up to $n = 10^9$?.

Maybe by "the conjecture" they mean the result about representation? It's not even clear what does it mean for Schinzel's Hypothesis to be "true up to $n = 10^9$", as it's not of the form $\forall n: \text{something}(n)$.

Schinzel's hypothesis lies upon Bouniakowsky conjecture (generalization extended to irreducible polynomials of Dirichlet's theorem of the arithmetic progression).
